# About matrices and the nilpotent property.

Tags: matrices

If an $n\times n$ square matrix $W$ has $r$ of its entries of value of zero (where $1 < r < n^2$) does there exist an integer $t > 1$ such that $W^t$ has $s$ entries being zero, with $s > r$?  Assume W is not unipotent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, other than nilpotent matrices, the entries will eventually all be nonzero. If the matrix has only one nonzero entry, either it is nilpotent (which is the case if the nonzero entry is off the diagonal) or all powers have that same entry nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

**Counterexample:** Consider $$W=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ and note that $W^n=W~\forall~n>1.$

Comment: What if W was not cyclic (where there exist an n such thar W^n = W) and W is not nilpotent and the absolute value of each entry is < C (where C is some constant) ? What happens then?

Comment: Consider $W=\begin{pmatrix}2&2\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$